# Did Obama defy precedent by not visiting the D-Day monument?

Tags: politics, world-war-ii, barack-obama

[image]

This seems like a very dubious picture, from a very clearly politically motivated website, but I was wondering if there was any truth to this picture?

Comment: The claim about campaigning with Air Force One is misleading at best. It's a complicated issue, but Snopes has a piece on this too https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/taxpayers-air-force-one/

Comment: I want to edit out the emotive word "defy" which isn't part of the claim, but I am having trouble thinking of a good replacement.

Comment: @Oddthinking I think that the emotive "defy" fits because the nature of this source plays on the pathos of the audience. The claim is that Obama selfishly disregarded a presidential standard, implying outright disrespect towards the fallen soldiers of the United States.

Comment: @Oddthinking how about [_break_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/break%20(with)%20precedent)?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

No, he did not.

[Snopes](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/false-only-obama-fails-to-visit-d-day-monument/) says:

> In fact, any public presidential activity paying tribute to fallen U.S. and Allied soldiers on the anniversary of D-Day has been an exception rather than the rule in recent years. Available White House presidential schedules for 6 June, going back to the beginning of the George W. Bush administration in 2001, list **no public events connected to D-Day in 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2003, or 2002**.
>
> Between 1944 and 2016 — a span of 72 years — four U.S. presidents have attended D-Day memorial ceremonies a total of seven times, and Barack Obama attended two of the seven.

The reason Snopes talks about "presidential activity [...] on the anniversary of D-Day" instead of going to "the D-Day Monument" is that there is not *the* D-Day monument.

As Snopes points out, there is the National D-Day Memorial, but no president has visited on D-Day since its opening in 2001, when Bush dedicated it on D-Day. There is the National World War II Memorial, but that has never seen a presidential visit on D-Day. And there are D-Day ceremonies in Normandy, but those have not been visited regularly by presidents (see also [Politifact](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2014/may/30/chain-email/chain-email-falsely-claims-obama-only-president-no/)).

Comment: Is there any info about the secondary claim "he made a campaign trip to California on Air Force 1"?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That seems to be [true](https://web.archive.org/web/20120606225957/http://www.whitehouse.gov/schedule/complete). [note that 2012 was actually an election year, so it doesn't seem that unreasonable to make campaign trips]

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Regarding the Air Force 1 part: I couldn't find any reliable information about that, but would just assume that it's true. I would guess that most presidents travel via Air Force 1 instead of using commercial airplanes (it's probably the same with the current president and his campaign rallies).

Comment: Air Force One is not a particular plane rather it is the call sign of whatever government plane the president happens to be flying on.  So if he was flying a government plane it is certainly "Air Force One" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Force_One

Comment: @AllInOne If he was flying in an *US Airforce* plane. If he's flying in an airplane or helicopter belonging to another service, it'll be "Army/Navy/Marine/Coast Guard One" as appropriate, a civilian aircraft would be Executive One. The president's helicopters are normally flown my Marines so Marine One would be the most common alternate designation. But when G. W. Bush Jr. flew to a carrier the aircraft he was onboard used the Navy One call sign. According to Wiki, only Coast Guard One is a notional designation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_of_the_President_of_the_United_States

Comment: Does Snopes rule out some kind of visitation that wasn't a "public event"? What does "public event" even mean in that context?

Comment: @jpmc26: You might see my CW answer below, where I'm trying to collect all Presidential June 6th activities from 1945 to 2012.  Already there are several June 6ths where the President never left the White House, or was traveling to some place not known to have any relevance to D-Day.  I'm guessing "public event" means "something listed on the President's official calendar".

Answer (score 126):

The daily schedules of past US presidents are, in many cases, publicly available.  So just for completeness, let's try to collect a list of what the sitting President was doing on June 6 of every year.  I think it'll be illustrative.

This is community wiki, so feel free to contribute.  Please include links. Any D-Day-related activities should go in **bold**.

- [**1945**](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/calendar/main.php?currMonth=6&currYear=1945&searchterm=&bool=AND&searchterm1=&yearstart=1945&yearend=1952&limit=10&lowerlimit=0) Truman had meetings all day.
- [**1946**](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/calendar/main.php?currMonth=6&currYear=1946&searchterm=&bool=AND&searchterm1=&yearstart=1945&yearend=1952&limit=10&lowerlimit=0) Truman had meetings, a luncheon for the president-elect of Colombia, and a press conference.
- [**1947**](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/calendar/main.php?currMonth=6&currYear=1947&searchterm=&bool=AND&searchterm1=&yearstart=1945&yearend=1952&limit=10&lowerlimit=0) Truman flew to Kansas City where he participated in activities with the Army's 35th Division, with which he had served in 1918.  No direct indication that D-Day was mentioned (though the 35th Division was one of the units that took part in the Normandy invasion).  There are no "D-Day monuments" in Missouri to my knowledge.   Truman also visited his mother.
- [**1948**](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/calendar/main.php?currMonth=6&currYear=1948&searchterm=&bool=AND&searchterm1=&yearstart=1945&yearend=1952&limit=10&lowerlimit=0) Truman traveled by train from Nebraska to Wyoming, giving a series of [speeches](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/publicpapers/index.php?pid=1651) along the way.  None of the speeches mentioned D-Day.

  (Note: 1948 was an election year, and this journey seems to have been, at least partly, a campaign activity.  Truman's speeches on June 6 were just fluff and not explicitly political, but some of his [other speeches](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/publicpapers/index.php?pid=1657) on the same trip seem to clearly be campaign speeches.  So it seems reasonable to say that, like Obama in 2012, *Truman spent June 6, 1948, campaigning.*)
- [**1949**](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/calendar/main.php?currMonth=6&currYear=1949&searchterm=&bool=AND&searchterm1=&yearstart=1945&yearend=1952&limit=10&lowerlimit=0) Truman had meetings all day, including lunch with several Cabinet secretaries.
- [**1950**](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/calendar/main.php?currMonth=6&currYear=1950&searchterm=&bool=AND&searchterm1=&yearstart=1945&yearend=1952&limit=10&lowerlimit=0) Truman had meetings all day.  In the evening he gave a speech to the Better Business Bureau.
- [**1951**](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/calendar/main.php?currMonth=6&currYear=1951&searchterm=&bool=AND&searchterm1=&yearstart=1945&yearend=1952&limit=10&lowerlimit=0) Truman had meetings all day.  In the evening he went to a Masonic Temple in Alexandria, Virginia.
- [**1952**](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/calendar/main.php?currMonth=6&currYear=1952&searchterm=&bool=AND&searchterm1=&yearstart=1945&yearend=1952&limit=10&lowerlimit=0) Truman traveled again to Missouri for a 35th Division reunion.

---

- [**1953**](https://www.eisenhower.archives.gov/research/online_documents/presidential_appointment_books/1953/June_1953.pdf) Eisenhower had meetings at the White House in the morning, then played golf all afternoon.
- [**1954**](https://www.eisenhower.archives.gov/research/online_documents/presidential_appointment_books/1954/June_1954.pdf) (*10th anniversary of D-Day*) Eisenhower spent the day at Camp David, and traveled back to the White House in the evening.  No appointments or official activities shown.
- [**1955**](https://www.eisenhower.archives.gov/research/online_documents/presidential_appointment_books/1955/June_1955.pdf) Eisenhower spent the day in West Point, NY, attending his 40-year class reunion at the US Military Academy.
- [**1956**](https://www.eisenhower.archives.gov/research/online_documents/presidential_appointment_books/1956/June_1956.pdf) Eisenhower had meetings at the White House in the morning, including receiving the newly appointed Chinese Ambassador.  He held a press conference, then at noon received a group of Young Republicans.  In the afternoon he took a quick flight to his farm in Gettysburg, PA, where he met some guests, then flew back, had a brief meeting, and had dinner with personal friends.
- [**1957**](https://www.eisenhower.archives.gov/research/online_documents/presidential_appointment_books/1957/June_1957.pdf) Eisenhower flew from Washington to Florida where he toured the USS Saratoga and spent the night on board.
- [**1958**](https://www.eisenhower.archives.gov/research/online_documents/presidential_appointment_books/1958/June_1958.pdf) Eisenhower had a full slate of meetings at the White House in the morning.  After lunch he had some more meetings and then went to the South Grounds to practice his golf.  Following a rest in the evening, he went to a dinner in his honor at the German Embassy.
- [**1959**](https://www.eisenhower.archives.gov/research/online_documents/presidential_appointment_books/1959/June_1959.pdf) Eisenhower was at his farm in Gettysburg.  He played golf in the morning, went skeet shooting in the afternoon, then gave a picnic in the evening for White House and Secret Service staff.
- [**1960**](https://www.eisenhower.archives.gov/research/online_documents/presidential_appointment_books/1960/June_1960.pdf) Eisenhower was once again in West Point, this time for his 45-year reunion.

---

- [**1961**](https://www.jfklibrary.org/Asset-Viewer/Archives/USSS-025-003.aspx) Kennedy arrived at the White House in the morning, having just returned from [a trip to Europe](https://history.state.gov/departmenthistory/travels/president/kennedy-john-f), including the Vienna Conference.  (The trip included a visit to Paris but no mention of Normandy.)  He was visited at the White House by members of Congress, and made a [TV broadcast](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=8180), which did not mention D-Day, in the evening.  (These records are a bit sketchy.)
- [**1962**](https://www.jfklibrary.org/Asset-Viewer/Archives/USSS-025-004.aspx) Kennedy flew out of Washington in the morning, apparently to [give a speech](http://digital-library.usma.edu/cdm/ref/collection/p16919coll13/id/4246) at the US Military Academy.  **His speech contained a brief, two-sentence reference to D-Day** ("Eighteen years ago today...").  He then returned to Washington, and in the afternoon he went to a luncheon given by the President of Cyprus. (Records are sketchy.)
- [**1963**](https://www.jfklibrary.org/Asset-Viewer/Archives/ELPP-006-007.aspx) Kennedy traveled from El Paso to San Diego.  He gave a speech at San Diego State College, toured the Marine Recruiting Depot and gave another speech there, and toured the aircraft carriers USS Oriskany and Kitty Hawk.  No indication as to whether D-Day was mentioned.

---

- [**1964**](http://www.lbjlibrary.net/assets/lbj_tools/daily_diary/pdf/1964/19640706.pdf) (*20th anniversary of D-Day*) Johnson spent the morning on his [ranch](https://www.nps.gov/lyjo/planyourvisit/visitlbjranch.htm) in Texas, and visited another ranch by helicopter to meet someone.  In the evening he flew back to the White House.
- [**1965**](http://www.lbjlibrary.net/assets/lbj_tools/daily_diary/pdf/1966/19660606.pdf) Johnson
  gave a commencement speech at Catholic University in the morning, had some meetings in the early afternoon, then spent the rest of the afternoon and evening on a cruise down the Potomac (marked STRICTLY OFF RECORD).
- [**1966**](http://www.lbjlibrary.net/assets/lbj_tools/daily_diary/pdf/1966/19660606.pdf) Johnson spent the day visiting various people on ranches in Texas.  Notable incidents include pulling a puppy into a swimming pool, and a helicopter engine disabled by grass clippings.
- [**1967**](http://www.lbjlibrary.net/assets/lbj_tools/daily_diary/pdf/1967/19670606.pdf) Johnson spent most of the day dealing with the outbreak of the [Six-Day War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six-Day_War).  He had several Hot Line conversations with Soviet Premier Kosygin.  He also met with Congressional leadership, had dental treatment, and ate broiled chicken for lunch (but did not overeat).  That night he gave a televised speech, apparently about the conflict in the Middle East and not about D-Day.
- [**1968**](http://www.lbjlibrary.net/assets/lbj_tools/daily_diary/pdf/1968/19680606.pdf) Johnson was awakened early in the morning with the news that [Robert F. Kennedy had died](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_of_Robert_F._Kennedy).  This dominated the day's events and he didn't leave the White House.      He gave a short televised [speech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2mE1cBSQgU) which dealt only with RFK's death and not with D-Day.  He also signed a bill, just passed by Congress, authorizing Secret Service protection for presidential candidates.

---

- [**1969**](https://www.nixonlibrary.gov/virtuallibrary/documents/PDD/1969/010%20June%201-15%201969.pdf) (*25th anniversary of D-Day*) Nixon spent most of his day in meetings with leaders of the [draft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_Service_System) at a [LORAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LORAN) station in California. Although he was at a military facility, the journal does not record any mentions of D-Day. He also spoke with aides at his home in California that evening.
- [**1970**](https://www.nixonlibrary.gov/virtuallibrary/documents/PDD/1970/029%20June%201-15%201970.pdf) Nixon spent his morning in meetings. Around 13:00, he flew/drove to Camp David. He spent most of the afternoon and evening making and receiving phone calls. However, he held a private graduation party for President Eisenhower’s grandchildren and watched a [movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith!) with them.
- [**1971**](https://www.nixonlibrary.gov/virtuallibrary/documents/PDD/1971/053%20June%201-15%201971.pdf) Nixon spent most of the day on the phone. He took a break to swim in the pool and watched a [movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cheyenne_Social_Club) with his family (he made phone calls during the movie).
- [**1972**](https://www.nixonlibrary.gov/virtuallibrary/documents/PDD/1972/077%20June%201-15%201972.pdf) Nixon spent most of the day in meetings, flying to Camp David around 16:00.
- [**1973**](https://www.nixonlibrary.gov/virtuallibrary/documents/PDD/1973/103%20July%201-15%201973.pdf) Nixon spent most of the morning and afternoon in meetings. He had a photo op with the press for just two minutes, and there’s no evidence in the journal that he mentioned D-Day during that time. He spent the evening in a motorboat with with the head of PR for [Procter & Gamble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procter_%26_Gamble). After dinner, he made a few phone calls.
- [**1974**](https://www.nixonlibrary.gov/virtuallibrary/documents/PDD/1974/125%20June%201-15%201974.pdf) (*30th anniversary of D-Day*) Nixon spent most of the day in meetings. At 10:44, he bid farewell to the [then-Prince of Saudi Arabia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahd_of_Saudi_Arabia) and the Saudi Arabian ambassador to the US. At that time, he also had a two-minute photo op with the press. As in 1973, the photo op was short, and in 1974 he was probably too busy seeing off the prince and the ambassador to mention D-Day. Around 13:00, he brought the prince back to the White House in the presence of the press. He had lunch with a large group of people (see pages 18–20 of the PDF), but there’s no mention of D-Day in the journal.

---

- [**1975**](https://www.fordlibrarymuseum.gov/library/document/0036/pdd750606.pdf) Ford had meetings in the White House most of the day. In the afternoon he hosted "a reception for new non-career federal executives in the Executive Branch."
- [**1976**](https://www.fordlibrarymuseum.gov/library/document/0036/pdd760606.pdf) Ford met with a number of senior Catholic officials in the morning. In the afternoon, he flew to New Jersey, where he designated the Great Falls of the Passaic River as a National Historic Site, and then attended and spoke at several receptions (for "business and civic leaders", and for various groups of New Jersey Republicans). In the evening he flew to Cleveland, Ohio, spoke at several more receptions of similar type, and had a brief press Q+A session. I can find no record of what he talked about in any of these speeches or at the Q+A session.

---

- [**1977**](https://www.jimmycarterlibrary.gov/assets/documents/diary/1977/d060677t.pdf) Carter had meetings all day.
- [**1978**](https://www.jimmycarterlibrary.gov/assets/documents/diary/1978/d060678t.pdf) Carter had meetings, got his hair cut in the afternoon, and practiced a speech he was going to give on the 7th in the evening.
- [**1979**](https://www.jimmycarterlibrary.gov/assets/documents/diary/1979/d060679t.pdf) Carter had meetings, had a photograph taken with an architect from Georgia, ate lunch with the Chancellor of West Germany, and had a brief press interaction when the Chancellor left.
- [**1980**](https://www.jimmycarterlibrary.gov/assets/documents/diary/1980/d060680t.pdf) Carter had meetings and a few photo ops (including one with the Junior Diabetes Foundation). In the evening he helicoptered to Camp David and watched a movie with his wife.

---

- [**1981**](https://www.reaganlibrary.gov/sites/default/files/digitallibrary/dailydiary/1981-06.pdf) Reagan was at Camp David all day, with an assortment of meetings and phone calls.
- [**1982**](https://www.reaganlibrary.gov/sites/default/files/digitallibrary/dailydiary/1982-06.pdf) Reagan was at the [G7 Summit](http://en.chateauversailles.fr/discover/history/versailles-summit-1982) in Versailles, France, but it doesn't appear that he traveled to Normandy at any point during the trip.  **The previous day, he had given a [radio address](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=42605) in which he made reference to the upcoming anniversary of D-Day.**
- [**1983**](https://www.reaganlibrary.gov/sites/default/files/digitallibrary/dailydiary/1983-06.pdf) Reagan was at the White House all day.  Highlights included awarding a posthumous medal to a deceased Coast Guard sailor, greeting the competitors in the National Spelling Bee, and a concert in the evening.
- [**1984**](https://www.reaganlibrary.gov/sites/default/files/digitallibrary/dailydiary/1984-06.pdf) (*40th anniversary of D-Day*) **Reagan visited the D-Day battlefield in Normandy.**
- [**1985**](https://www.reaganlibrary.gov/sites/default/files/digitallibrary/dailydiary/1985-06.pdf) Reagan was in Atlanta, Georgia and Birmingham, Alabama. He gave a [speech](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=38734) at a high school in Atlanta, which did not mention D-Day.  According to his [personal diary](https://www.reaganfoundation.org/ronald-reagan/white-house-diaries/diary-entry-06061985/) the trip to Birmingham was a fundraiser for [Senator Jeremiah Denton](https://www.reaganfoundation.org/ronald-reagan/white-house-diaries/diary-entry-06061985/).
- [**1986**](https://www.reaganfoundation.org/ronald-reagan/white-house-diaries/diary-entry-06061982/) Reagan had meetings and various business at the White House, then flew to Camp David in the afternoon, where he watched the movie "Cobra".
- [**1987**](https://www.reaganlibrary.gov/sites/default/files/digitallibrary/dailydiary/1987-06.pdf) Reagan spent the day in Rome, where he met with the Pope.  No references to D-Day in his [personal diary](https://www.reaganfoundation.org/ronald-reagan/white-house-diaries/diary-entry-06061987/).  (Note to avoid confusion: the PDF for his official schedule erroneously includes his schedule for July 6 where June 6 should go.)
- [**1988**](https://www.reaganlibrary.gov/sites/default/files/digitallibrary/dailydiary/1988-06.pdf) Reagan had meetings at the White House, and gave a speech to a conference of gas industry executives.

---

- **1989** **George H. W. Bush releases a [statement on the 45th anniversary of D-Day](https://bush41library.tamu.edu/archives/public-papers/508).**
- **1990** George H. W. Bush
- **1991** George H. W. Bush
- **1992** George H. W. Bush

---

- [**1993**](https://clinton.presidentiallibraries.us/items/show/12636) Clinton attended church in the morning and played Golf, and in the evening attended [the memorial Mass for the 25-year anniversary of Robert F. Kennedy's death](http://articles.baltimoresun.com/1993-06-07/news/1993158153_1_robert-kennedy-edward-kennedy-president-kennedy) at Arlington National Cemetery which was followed by a private reception at Hickory Hill, a Kennedy compound. No reference to D-Day was made in [the speech](https://millercenter.org/the-presidency/presidential-speeches/june-6-1993-speech-25th-anniversary-memorial-mass-robert-f).
- [**1994**](https://clinton.presidentiallibraries.us/items/show/12649) (*50th anniversary of D-Day*) **Clinton attends D-Day ceremonies at Pointe du Hoc, Utah Beach, Omaha Beach and Colleville U.S. Cemetery**, all as part of a [weeklong European tour in celebration of the D-Day anniversary](https://www.upi.com/Archives/1994/06/01/Clinton-arrives-in-Rome-for-D-Day-tour/9972770443200/).
- [**1995**](https://clinton.presidentiallibraries.us/items/show/12662) Clinton attends various Oval Office meetings, is on the phone to President Assad of Syria and meets Prime Minister Horn of Hungary. In the afternoon he holds a [speech](https://clintonwhitehouse6.archives.gov/1995/06/1995-06-06-president-remarks-at-nga-summit-on-young-children.html) at the NGA National Summit on Young Children, which does not mention D-Day.
- [**1996**](https://clinton.presidentiallibraries.us/items/show/12675) Clinton attends various events surrounding the National Home Ownership Summit. No D-Day references in [the speech](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/?pid=52916).  Besides that, a number of meetings and a reception for the White House Environment Day conference.
- [**1997**](https://clinton.presidentiallibraries.us/items/show/12688) Clinton had the day off for family time, more precisely for his daughter Chelsea's graduation from [Sidwell Fiends School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidwell_Friends_School#Notable_alumni).
- [**1998**](https://clinton.presidentiallibraries.us/items/show/12701) Clinton is at Camp David, having the day and evening off.
- [**1999**](https://clinton.presidentiallibraries.us/items/show/12714) Clinton is again at Camp David with no scheduled activities apart from some briefing and foreign policy phone calls.
- [**2000**](https://clinton.presidentiallibraries.us/items/show/12727) Clinton meets Jordanian King Abdullah at the White House. No other events.

---

- [**2001**](https://georgewbushlibrary.smu.edu/en/Research/Digital%20Library/~/media/A2D6C4ECA06F49779C9D3152AE07CA96.ashx) **George W. Bush [participates](https://georgewbush-whitehouse.archives.gov/news/releases/2001/06/20010606-2.html) in the dedication of the national D day memorial in Virginia.  Which is most likely the D day monument mentioned in the info graphic.**
- [**2002**](https://www.nytimes.com/2002/05/27/international/bush-takes-memorial-day-tour-of-normandy-beaches.html) **George W. Bush speaks at a cemetery in Normandy**
- **2003** George W. Bush
- [**2004**](https://georgewbush-whitehouse.archives.gov/news/releases/2004/06/20040606.html) (*60th anniversary of D-Day*) **George W. Bush speaks at a D-Day event in Normandy**
- **2005** George W. Bush
- **2006** George W. Bush
- **2007** George W. Bush
- **2008** George W. Bush

---

- [**2009**](https://www.nytimes.com/2009/06/07/world/europe/07prexy.html) **Obama speaks at a D-Day event in Normandy**
- **2010** Obama
- [**2011**](https://web.archive.org/web/20110609112218/http://www.whitehouse.gov/schedule/complete/2011-W24) Obama meets with the national security team, is interviewed by the media, and meets with senior advisors
- [**2012**](https://web.archive.org/web/20120606225957/http://www.whitehouse.gov/schedule/complete) Obama holds a campaign rally in California
- [**2013**](https://web.archive.org/web/20130607011249/http://www.whitehouse.gov/schedule/complete/2013-W23) Obama visits a middle school in North Carolina, meets with the Crown Prince of Bahrain, and speaks at a DSCC event.
- [**2014**](https://obamawhitehouse.archives.gov/the-press-office/2014/06/06/remarks-president-obama-70th-anniversary-d-day-omaha-beach-normandy) (*70th anniversary of D-Day*) **Obama speaks at D-Day ceremony in Normandy**
- **2015** Obama
- **2016** Obama

---

- **2017** Trump
- **2018** Trump

Comment: An amazingly comprehensive answer, worthy of the skeptics site.

Comment: When Truman catches a train from Nebraska to Wyoming, is that train Executive One?

Comment: @Anthony: "Union Pacific One" :-)

Comment: This is one of the best answers on the whole SE network, possibly second only to the "you can't parse html with regex"-one. Chapeau.

Comment: Those diaries are fascinating to read.

Comment: Can we agree on a notation (similar to bolding references to D-Day) for when a president was doing anything seemingly campaigning-related? It feels almost as important for discrediting the poster as demonstrating that Obama wasn't the first president to not celebrate/honor/visit-some-fictional-site D-Day on June 6th.

Comment: I don't want to edit the contribution of other users, but I think it would be better if only actual *events* whose primary topic were D-day were marked in bold. It will be very very difficult to find all casual references presidents made to D-Day in otherwise unrelated speeches. So bolding these (eg Kennedy in 1962 or Reagan in 1982) somewhat distorts the picture.

Comment: @Anthony Bush actually went three times (that I am aware of) to Normandy on D-Day. Obama seems to be the president that went second-most often (two times).

Comment: @tim - I guess I meant Reagan was first. Per your notation suggestion (only bolding definitive D-Day events), I'll take the opposing stance and say that highlighting anything remotely relevant (and verifiably on the record) makes this list more exhaustive and thus clearly illuminates the extent of Presidential tributes that are verifiable and removes the ability for a naysayer to say something like "but what about Reagan in 82? What else are you choosing to overlook?" etc.

Comment: For Trump in 2018, you might add how Trump's ambassador to Germany mentioned "Celebrating D-Day." on D-day.

Comment: The only pattern I'm seeing in here is that on every even 10th year anniversary, starting with the 40th (Reagan), the POTUS has gone to France to do something associated with commemorating D-Day. Obama when it was his turn (70'th) did it just like GWB, Clinton, and Reagan before him.

Comment: Anyone near College Station, TX feel like looking at [George H.W. Bush's daily diary](https://bush41library.tamu.edu/archives/finding-aids/daily-diary/appointments) (Boxes 10, 40, 71, 104)?

Comment: For a moment I was confused why 1944 and earlier weren't included, then I felt dumb. Very comprehensive list, and very good job compiling it, to everyone involved!

Comment: @NicHartley: Eisenhower of course had some pretty significant D-Day related activities on June 6, 1944, though he didn't actually arrive in Normandy until June 7.  But it's not quite the same...